# How to use Django views and template tag simultanosly?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

In my Django-template:

```
<div class="A">
    {% url renders_data object.id %}
</div>
<div class="B">
    {% render_data object.id %}
</div>
```

Div `A` is common way to call a method in `views.py` whereas Div `B` is for template tags.

User will open a link. Let's say: `/myapp/test/` a page will open contain two template tag section at the page. Name of this tag is `render_data` I want to load the data into each template tag with `Ajax`. To work with it we need `request.ajax:`. That is why i thought to write views method. I thought to complete it with the following way:

I wrote the exact copy of `template tag` in `views.py` (renders_data with passing object_id parameter) and render it to the right template. When i open the `maypp/test` after removing the `div A` from template. It shows the `URL` (`myapp/test/<object_id>`) in each template tags section (each corner) except the data. Is their any possibility to show the context except this URL [See the image when i choose this option](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21766438/Screenshot%20at%202012-06-19%2001_34_22.png)

Second i also thought to import views method (`renders_data`) in template tag (`render_data`). So that data will display in each corner and `request.Ajax:` will also work. if this can be possible then how?

I am not able to solve this issue. please help me :(

See how the render_data looks like:

```
 @register.simple_tag
 def render_widget(object_id):
     from myapp.plugins.model import Widgetsetting
     widget_setting = Widetsetting.objects.get(id = object_id)
     widget = widget_settings.get_widget()
     template_name = widget.template_name
     context = widget.context(widget=widget_settings)
     t =  get_template("widgets/%s" % template_name)
     return t.render(Context(context))
```

Comment: Didn't understand your question! if you need a ajax call then write the code for it. And please elaborate it with what you have tried and what errors are coming?

Comment: @Ahsan I want to load the data in template tags with Ajax. How should i do this?

This is my question. So to this i tried two approaches and there is no error occurring(I have already mentioned in question). When i tried with the first one it shows me URL in template tag section in Django template.

Comment: @Ahsan See the image for first option (updated in question)

Comment: could you please post the code for your `render_data` templatetag... is it a `simpletag`, `inclusiontag` or it is done the long way with a `RenderDataNode` class etc ?

Comment: your dropbox link doesn't work

Comment: what is the widget_settings object?

Comment: the view should take an object_id but the templatetag takes a widget_settings?

Comment: @Anentropic Now i updated it. Actually this template tag taking an id on the basis it i got the objects of Widgetsetting model class which help us
 to fetch the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted something like below should work...

in views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from netadmin.plugins.templatetags.widgets import render_widget

def ajax_render_data(request, object_id):
    return HttpResponse(render_widget(object_id))
```

in your django template:
(you said you want several of these on the page, so I'm going to use a loop in the django template, I don't know what your widget collection is called but I'm sure you can work it out for your particular case)

```
<div class="widgets-container">
    {% for widget_settings in widgetsettings.objects.all %}
    <div class="widget-content" id="widget-content-{{ widget_settings.pk }}">
        not loaded yet
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
// here we use django to render the ajax urls into an object
// in javascript so we can use it on the client side 
var ajax_urls = {
  {% for widget_settings in widgetsettings.objects.all %}
    "{{ widget_settings.pk }}: "{% url ajax_render_data widget_settings.pk %}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
};

// (I'll assume you're using jQuery)
// start the ajax calls when the page is loaded:
$(document).ready(loadWidgets());

function loadWidgets() {
    // loop over the urls we provided from django:
    jQuery.each(ajax_urls, function(widget_id, url) {
        // do the ajax call:
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            // put the content into the widget div:
            $('#widget-content-'+widget_id).html(data);
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('netadmin.plugins.ajax_view',
    url(r'^ajax/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'ajax_render_data', name='ajax_render_data'),
)
```

Comment: This should be write in views.py. Is the Ajax section are also written in this method?. One more thing which link should i open this ajax_render_data has it's different url pattern and that template tag has it different. I mean to say that there is a base.html exist . In which i add template tag code {{render_data object.id}}. If i opened this one then how views section will work?

Comment: see edited answer. you can leave out the `{% render_widget widget_settings.pk %}` from the html template if you only ever want to load the content via ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the giving time on this issue. I have a  last question, Yes i want to load only with the Ajax but i have a doubt regarding this If i remove the {% render_widget...%} then how the data will show on template. JS is only for fetching the data continously from the given url i.e. { url ajax_rener...}. Mean while this url return HttpResponse(render_widget(object_id)). Now we come into render_widget method and finally it returns t.render(Context...). Then it need some place in template to load it.